# Где должны быть запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

"Иванов Иван Иванович, полковник внутренней службы, доктор юридических наук, профессор".

Answer (score 1):

Если предложение имеет законченный вид, то запятые поставлены правильно, только в конце нужна точка.